# NodeJS MongoDB Connection string problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

I'm new to using MongoDB and would appreciate some help in replicating the following command in my NodeJS application.

```
mongo --host dds-xxxx.mongodb.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717 -u root -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I need to be able to connect with these credentials from Node, preferably but not necessarily using the MongoJS library. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again.

Comment: I think this is a good place to start looking: https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database
```

In your case:

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:password@dds-xxxx.mongodb.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717/admin
```

You can find more at: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html